# How to align an element to the bottom of a layout and avoid it "covering" previous elements

Tags: android, android-layout

The title is not very clear, so I'll try to explain better.

I have a RelativeLayout with an editable text box at its bottom. Before this editable textfield I have a ListView. Right now, if the list contains many elements, the last list rows are not shown because they are "under" the editable text field.

How can I avoid this problem and make the ListView end before the editable text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the listview widget a attribute android:layout_above="@id/edittextid"

Answer (score 0):

set above property of listview in your xml